# announce a route without add it to routing table

Tags: cisco

i have two bgp session , one of them is with my IP transit and another one is with my customer, my customer send a /32 to me by bgp and community 12345:666 and i want to announce it to my IP transit without install this route in my route table,
is it possible ? if yes, any idea?

Comment: How would your transit reach that customer of yours if you don’t have the route in your routing table? The answer to that should give you a hint on how to configure this.

Comment: Adding more details on the current topology and configurations may help as well. Is 12345:666 a blackhole community by any chance?

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to manually enter the route - you want it to be automatically advertised from one neighbor to the other? As in being redistributed?

Comment: i just want receive route from neighbour 1.2.3.4 and readvertise to 9.8.7.6 without change anything and without add it to my route table just it, and 12345:666 is blackhole community,

Comment: Remember the ISPs will not advertise any prefix longer than `/24` on the public Internet, so that advertisement will not go very far.

Comment: @ronmaupin most transit providers accept /32 blackhole routes.

Comment: Right, but it will not go very far. I doubt it goes past the next ISP.

Comment: That’s not the point, they need to discard traffic to that /32 in their network so your uplinks don’t get saturated. And they may adjust the community to something used by their peers and transits so it may not even reach their network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IOS-XR, you can use the BGP `table-policy` to prevent routes from being installed in the main RIB while still announcing them to BGP neighbors.

Cisco's docs on this feature aren't great, but here are some links:

- https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/crs/software/crs_r4-0/routing/command/reference/rr40crs1book_chapter1.html#wp1379308877
- https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr9000/software/asr9k-r6-5/routing/configuration/guide/b-routing-cg-asr9000-65x/b-routing-cg-asr9000-65x_chapter_01011.html#con_1310956

As you asked about Arista EOS and Cisco NX-OS in a follow-up comment:

- NX-OS has `router bgp <asn>` `table-map <route map name>` which is functionally similar to the XR table-policy.
- Arista EOS has `router bgp` `bgp route install-map <route map name>`.  This governs what routes are installed to the FIB (hardware) but does not affect the main RIB.

Comment: im using nexus 3064 and arista , any idea on them?